# PHP Array Foreach Tittle

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying to show some headers and footers to numbers, the array contains dates and what I want is that these are separated by date.

the ideal would only declare one header and one footer.

I need to do 2 foreach ?? or anyone has any idea?, thx

```
<?php 
$datos = array(
  array("date" => "2018"),

  array("date" => "2016"),
  array("date" => "2016"),

  array("date" => "2015"),
  array("date" => "2015"),
  array("date" => "2015"),
  array("date" => "2015"),      

  array("date" => "2014"),
  array("date" => "2014"),

  array("date" => "2005"),
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($datos);
echo "</pre>";

echo "HEADER TOP<br>";
foreach ($datos as $row) {
  if ($datos['date'] != @$lezte_jahr){
    echo "FOOTER <br><br><br> HEADER ";
  }
  echo $row['date'] . "  ";
  $lezte_jahr = $row['date'];
}
echo "FOOTER TOP<br>";
?>
```

i like result, but i dont know how XD

```
--a--
2018
--b--

--a--
2016
2016
--b--

--a--
2015
2015
2015
2015
--b--

--a--
2014
2014
--b--

--a--
2005
--b--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply loop through and store the last echoed date and compare the same with next date in array.

```
<?php
$datos = array
  (
  array("date" => "2018"),

  array("date" => "2016"),
  array("date" => "2016"),

  array("date" => "2015"),
  array("date" => "2015"),
  array("date" => "2015"),
  array("date" => "2015"),      

  array("date" => "2014"),
  array("date" => "2014"),

  array("date" => "2005"),
  );

foreach($datos as $key => $dt) {
    if(isset($last) && $last != $dt['date'])
        echo '--b--' . PHP_EOL . '--a--' . PHP_EOL;
    if(!isset($last))
        echo '--a--'. PHP_EOL;

    echo $dt['date']. PHP_EOL;

    if($key == count($datos) -1)
        echo '--b--';

    $last = $dt['date'];
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/570468